# How to list user and role assigned to them in Sybase DB

Tags: sap-ase

Kindly help me with SQL statement which can list the users and the role assigned to them in Sybase DB.

Need to capture  users\roles who have following authorisations:

```
ALTER ANY TABLE
CREATE ANY TABLE
DELETE ANY TABLE
DROP ANY TABLE
GRANT ANY ROLE
UPDATE ANY TABLE
DROP ANY ROLE
GRANT ANY OBJECT PRIVILEDGE
GRANT ANY PRIVILEDGE
ALTER USER
ALTER PROFILE
ALTER DATABASE
BECOME USER
CREATE ANY RULE
DROP USER
```

Comment: Some of those authorizations don't exist (eg, `GRANT ANY *`, `BECOME USER`) in ASE so I'm not sure where they came from; as for the 'valid' entries I'd suggest taking a look at the source code for the system stored proc `sp_displayroles` to see where the info is coming from and then roll your own code based on your specific requirements (eg, if a user has been assigned a role, or nested role, do you need to recursively expand these roles to find the basic permissions the user has access to?)

Comment: yes, i need to check what permissions are assigned to the user. can you help me with the code?